# How to call figures automatically for print and web with different file namings but in the same Art folder

Tags: graphics

I'm using 2 types of figures; colour figures for web and black & white for print.

But, both these files are in the same folder with the namings mentioned below.

`abcdef.eps`          for Print figures
`abcdef_online.eps`   for Web figures

During, web PDF I need to call `abcdef_online.eps` and for printer `abcdef.eps`.

Is there any automation script to pick the figures automatically for different stages from the same folder?

Please note that for web PDF, not all the figures will be in colour, for example out of 6 figures only 3 figures (1,3, and 5) are in colour.

```
one_online.eps
two.eps
three_online.eps
four.eps
five_online.eps
six.eps
```

Could any one guide me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are *only* working with a compilation sequence that uses EPS images *and* supplying the image names *without* extension, the following redefinition of `\includegraphics` would work:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2_online.eps}{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2_online.eps}}{% 1 Online/colour
    \oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}% 2 Regular
  }% 3
}
```

where you would use

\includegraphics{abcdef}

to include an image (no extension). The updated version of `\includegraphics` will check whether `abcdef_online.eps` exists, and include it, otherwise it will default to `abcdef.eps`. Commenting out lines 1 & 3 will remove the colour option altogether (for printed media).

The above restriction limits you to a specific compilation sequence (like LaTeX > dvips > epstopdf, for PDF output). If you wish to use pdflatex and have supplied corresponding PDF images, you can change the appropriate lines in the redefinition of `\includegraphics`. If you wish for the above technique to be more general in nature (and therefore work for any sequence automatically), you would have to search for the existence of files based on their extensions as indicated by the graphics driver - a little more expensive but doable.

Comment: The above said coding is working fine. Thanks for your immediate response.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you produce the documents. Here's how I would proceed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\cincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \ifdefined\onlineversion
    \IfFileExists{#2_online.eps}%
      {\includegraphics[#1]{#2_online}}%
      {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \else
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

Something with a picture

\cincludegraphics{abcdef}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this file, say `one.tex`, as

```
latex one
```

the file `abcdef.eps` would be loaded. If I call it with

```
latex -jobname one-online "\def\onlineversion{}\input{one}"
```

then `abcdef_online.eps` would be loaded (or, if non existent, `abcdef.eps`).